# Deploying ASP.Net Core application to Azure Website using Visual Studio Team Services has an ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE error.

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, msdeploy

I'm working on deploying an ASP.NET Core application stored in Git on Visual Studio Team Services. I've been following this process (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure); however, I receive the following error on the deployment step, and I'm running into a brick wall. I have verified that I have an SSL cert on xxx.com and www.xxx.com, but it still is failing. Any Ideas?

> Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLEMore Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("www.xxx.com"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.Error count: 1.

Comment: Can you share the settings of your build definition? If you are trying to deploy to Azure Website, the remote computer URL is incorrect. Usually, it should like this: https://yourwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following script in "PublishAspNet5Website.ps1" to see which is the correct MSDeploy URL:

```
Write-Output $website.EnabledHostNames[0]
Write-Output $website.EnabledHostNames[1]
Write-Output $website.EnabledHostNames[2]
...
```

Links for your reference:

[Resolve an ASP.NET 5 Deployment Issue to Azure Web App Slot](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/09/09/resolve-an-asp-net-5-deployment-issue-to-azure-web-app-slot/)

[MSDeploy to Azure Web App: Could not connect to the remote computer using the specified process (“Web Management Service”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435909/msdeploy-to-azure-web-app-could-not-connect-to-the-remote-computer-using-the-sp)